# print all python Structure field values

Tags: python, structure, ctypes

I've trying to write a small program which could read .h file, then generate ctypes.Structure classes from struct in .h file. Then i'm reading binary file into the Structures. And then i need to print out all of the Structure field values (including arrays and subStructures). How can i do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is basic function that print all fields and sub-structures.

```
def f(obj):
    for k,v in obj.__dict__.items():
        print k ,v
        if hasattr(v,'__dict__'):
            f(v)
```

Of course, you can add conditions to the function, to filter out unneeded data etc.

Answer (score 5):

There is already a tool that does this.
(*No need to re-invent the wheel*).

See: https://github.com/davidjamesca/ctypesgen